# How to solve “ AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'pred' ” error?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am working on k-means clustering analysis and trying to plot the clusters. However the code I have encounters the error:

> AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'pred'

My code:

```
#scale features 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_df = scaler.fit_transform(df)

# fitting multiple k-means algorithms and storing the values in an empty list

SSE = []
for cluster in range(1,40):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_jobs = -1, n_clusters = cluster, init='k-means++')
    kmeans.fit(scaled_df)
    SSE.append(kmeans.inertia_)

# converting the results into a dataframe and plotting them
frame = pd.DataFrame({'Cluster':range(1,40), 'SSE':SSE})
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.plot(frame['Cluster'], frame['SSE'], marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('Inertia')

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=16, init ='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10,random_state=0 )
pred = kmeans.fit_predict(scaled_df)

#Plot All K-Means Clusters
#Getting unique labels
u_labels = np.unique(pred)

#plotting the results:
for i in u_labels:
    plt.scatter(scaled_df[pred == i , 0], scaled_df[pred == i , 1], pred = i)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I have 18 attributes to be clustered and would also appreciate any help in getting the attributes within each cluster. Thanks!

I have tried to plot the first 5 clusters individually:

```
plt.scatter(scaled_df_uk19[pred==0, 0], scaled_df_uk19[pred==0, 1], s=100, c='red', label ='Cluster 1')
plt.scatter(scaled_df_uk19[pred==1, 0], scaled_df_uk19[pred==1, 1], s=100, c='blue', label ='Cluster 2')
plt.scatter(scaled_df_uk19[pred==2, 0], scaled_df_uk19[pred==2, 1], s=100, c='green', label ='Cluster 3')
plt.scatter(scaled_df_uk19[pred==3, 0], scaled_df_uk19[pred==3, 1], s=100, c='cyan', label ='Cluster 4')
plt.scatter(scaled_df_uk19[pred==4, 0], scaled_df_uk19[pred==4, 1], s=100, c='magenta', label ='Cluster 5')
```

It results in the following which I suppose is abit odd?

[image]

Edit: When I removed the pred=i argument within the scatter function, the plot shows:

It does not look like the usual cluster plots. Can anyone kindly explain why this may happen? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You're passing `pred=i` to `plt.scatter`, is that your intention. I don't think scatter has a `pred` argument?

Comment: @DavidWaterworth, I tried without the pred argument and got this warning: No handles with labels found to put in legend. Otherwise, the plot does show. Any advice?

Comment: @mmbbb  Make pred = label and use plt.scatter(scaled_df[label == i , 0], scaled_df[label == i , 1], label = i)